# Load gzipped RDF source files with Virtuoso's Bulk loading process

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

I would like to load a batch of gzipped RDF source files in Virtuoso. Currently I use the following bash script:

```
for file in $(find `pwd` -type f -name "*.gz"); do isql -S <port> "EXEC=DB.DBA.TTLP_MT(gz_file_open('$file'), '', '<graph>', 480, 0, 1);"; done
```

However, I prefer to use [the bulk loading process](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader#Bulk%20loading%20process). So far I have only managed to do so by first unzipping all the files, taking massive ammounts of hd space, since the zip ratio typically is around 90% 
Is there a way to instruct the bulk loading process of virtuoso to work with gzipped RDF source files as input?

Answer (score 2):

Virtuoso can also work with gzipped files. You don't need to extract them.
ld_dir_all() or ld_dir() will take care of that (as you can see here: [click](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir.html))